# stopping a thread when another thread is done.

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

i am trying to run 2 threads, the first one has a function1 target, this function should read a value from a machine, and while this value =0, the output 0 is saved in an array. When this value is not 0 anymore, the output 1 should be saved in this array. Then the queue must return this list. The second thread has a function2 as a target, and this function is doing something else. I will try to show it in the following code:

```
import threading
from multiprocessing import Queue
def func1(queue_in):
    list=[]
    while value_from_machine==0: #this value will always be refreshed and read again
        list.append(0)
        queue_in.put(list) 
    list.append(1) #when the value from the machine is not 0 anymore, put a 1 in the list
    queue_in.put(list)

def func2():
    #doing something else...

q_out=Queue()

thread1=threading.Thread(target=func1,args=(q_out))
thread2=threading.Thread(target=func2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

q_value=q_out.get()

if sum(q_value)==1:
    #print something
else:
    #print something else
```

now the problem is I want the first thread to stop when the second thread is done. Another thing is i am not sure about is the queue as output in the first function. Is it good to have a queue in the while loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about standard method - setting up an [Event](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=event#event-objects)?

```
from threading import Thread, Event
from Queue import Queue
from time import sleep

def func1(queue_in, done):
    while not done.is_set():
        queue_in.put_nowait(1)
        print 'func1 added new item to the queue_in'
        sleep(1)
    print 'func1 has finished'

def func2(done):
    x = 0
    while x < 3:
        sleep(2)
        x += 1
        print 'func2 processed %s item(s)' % x
    print 'func2 has finished'
    done.set()

q_out = Queue()
done  = Event()

thread1 = Thread(target=func1, args=[q_out, done]).start()
thread2 = Thread(target=func2, args=[done]).start()
```

Output:

```
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func2 processed 1 item(s)
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func2 processed 2 item(s)
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func1 added new item to the queue_in
func2 processed 3 item(s)
func2 has finished
func1 has finished
```

Comment: shouldn't the event name be given as a parameter in the 1st function? then it will be given as an argument in the first thread

Comment: Indeed it's better if `Event` is passed via function arguments. I updated my answer to show you task workflow.

Comment: ok that's the correct answer I think, I will try it, and if it didn't work, this means that the machine i am using will crash due to some other internal reasons, but I think this code is right so thank you !